# Как определить удовлетворяет ли байт шаблону 1х110ххх?

Tags: ассемблер

Как определить удовлетворяет ли данный байт шаблону 1х110ххх, где символ "х" означает, что содержимое данного бита несущественно? Ассемблер, используя команды работы с битами.

Comment: Ассемблер какого процессора ? И что вы пытались сделать самостоятельно

Comment: tasm для архитектуры x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вскидку два варианта:

1. AND с 10111000 т.е. оставляем только исследуемые биты и убеждаемся, что полученный результат точно равен требуемому 10110000
2. Сначала XOR с 10110000, т.е. делаем требуемые биты 0, если они именно такие как надо, потом маскируем оставшиеся биты AND с 10111000, и убеждаемся, что результат 0 (т.е. ZF установлен)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.